# Modify all HTTP traffic on an OS X

Tags: macos, http

Imagine an application that while running injects a "Hello world" message on every web page you visit.

How do I monitor and modify all HTTP traffic happening on an OS X machine?

Monitoring and modifying all browser traffic would be good enough as well.

Solution can be language agnostic; Python would be awesome.

Answer (score 2):

You can try tcpdump for monitoring. If You are interested in editing html try adding custom javascript for example with greasemonkey. If You want change headers and stuff like that try http://portswigger.net/proxy/.

Comment: The solution needs to be cross-browser. A grease monkey script would unfortunately not do the job

Comment: so only way is proxy (or lower level staff like tcp sniffing).  But I will on computers that You can control or that are in network that you can control.

Answer (score 1):

[GlimmerBlocker](http://glimmerblocker.org/) achieves this by implementing a HTTP proxy server and routing all traffic through it — allowing it to modify pages as it goes along. In this instance, it blocks adverts and modifies pages to provide more features.

I imagine that most other ways of implementing this would require root etc access to do.

Comment: This is a great link! I'll look through its source to find out what it does. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) has a rewrite facility.

Comment: I need a programmatic solution. Thanks for the link though!

Answer (score 1):

How about writing "proxy" app in php? Fetching web pages in php is easy. You can make form for taking url, fetch the website, customize it and then output it...

**//edit, another soulution (good if you use Firefox and like java script):**
You can try  [Greasemonkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey)